# Meaning of the word "zafeer" in quran

Tags: naming, arabic-translation, definitions

My son who is four years old now his name is zafeer. When we checked it has two meanings. When the word starts with "za" it's meaning is not good but when it starts with "dha"(which my son's name is) it's meaning are nice. But both the words are pronounced same only meanings are different.

Please advise what we should do?

Should we change the name or it's fine??

Comment: zafeer زفير in Arabic has two meanings expiration and sighing...

Comment: Can you please explain it more?...my son's name starts with letter "dha" not "za".

Comment: I still don't know how you pronounce it nor where and from which language you have taken the name so how could i explain?

Answer (score -1):

if it's dha (the Winner) it's nice
wheter it's zafeer(expiration), it has a strange but still a good meaning.